# How to put a Horizontal Ray (hray) on every ema cross?

Tags: arrays, pine-script

```
//@version=4

// Define variables
// 5 and 13 EMAs
ema5 = ema(close, 5)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)

// Use the crossover() function to detect when the EMAs cross
cross = crossover(ema5, ema13)

// Plot horizontal ray on chart
// Use the hline() function to plot the hray
// The hray is plotted when the EMAs cross (cross == true)
if cross
    hline(ema5[1], linewidth=2, color=color.red, title="5 EMA and 13 EMA Cross")
endif

// Hide the EMAs from the chart
plot(ema5, title="EMA 5", display=hidden)
plot(ema13, title="EMA 13", display=hidden)
```

I simply want to put a horizontal ray on every ema cross. Not sure how to get this to work, your input would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `hline()` function in the local scope. You should use [line.new()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew) instead.

Comment: line.new() doesn't work either..

Comment: line.new() doesn't work either..

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then. You can ask a new question.